# select rows in a table and then extract key and search in the other table and show the rows in R shiny

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, shiny-server

I have a dataset like this.

[image]
I made a new dataset and in this new one, I put unique rows of my original dataset. the new dataset shown in the dashboard and user can select some rows. based which rows selected I extracted the name like "PA0001" and now I have search all rows with this name in the original dataset and show to users.
my code is like below:

```
ui <- luidPage( 
 titlePanel("Prototype of Project"),
br(),
 br(),


  mainPanel(
     DT::dataTableOutput("main_table"),

    br(), be(),

     tableOutput("gene_data")

  )


  )


server <- function(input, output) {


  output$main_table <- DT::renderDataTable({
    data_search = distinct(data[,1:3])
     data_search
  },filter = "top")

    output$gene_data = renderTable({
    s = input$main_table_rows_selected
    data_search = distinct(data[,1:3])
    gene_name = data_search[s,1]
    print(gene_name)
    selected_row = data[data$Locus_Tag %in% gene_name,]
    print(selected_row)

    selected_row

   })


   }
```

the problem is: when I select one rows everything is fine, but when I select more rows my selected_row data frame is empty.

Comment: You're much more likely to get an answer if you provide us with a simple, self-contained example.  That is, code and data that we can run ourselves to investigate your problem.

Comment: what happens when you change `gene_name = data_search[s,1]`to `gene_name = data_search[[1]][s]`?